# Jlist getSelectValue select both values

Tags: swing, jbutton, jlist

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoDIv.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8drCu.png)
Self explains with the pics
The Question is why are both selected as true (same goes with deny button)? Basically i don't know what's going on but every time i made a selection then select something else in the Jlist then selecting back the original item somehow when i click [accept] button will set both as true.

update:i just found out that selecting Tony then Ada then click on accept will still set both set.flag"true".

```
  import java.awt.EventQueue;
  import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
  import javax.swing.JTable;
  import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
  import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
  import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Color;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JList;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;
  import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
  import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

 public class Coord {

private Client test = new Client();
private Client test2 = new Client();
private Client test3 = new Client();
private JFrame frame;
private JTable Infotable;
private DefaultTableModel InfoViewModel = new DefaultTableModel();
private DefaultListModel Lmodel = new DefaultListModel();
private JTable table;
private JTable table_1;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private ArrayList<Client> clientees= new ArrayList<Client>();



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Coord window = new Coord();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Coord() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    test2.setName("Ada Fong");  // using it for tests
    test3.setName("wuing doig");
    clientees.add(test);
    clientees.add(test2);   
    clientees.add(test3);   //
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1370, 746);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);



    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Main", null, panel, null);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblClientees = new JLabel("Clientees");
    lblClientees.setBounds(20, 24, 209, 14);
    panel.add(lblClientees);

    final JButton AcceptButton = new JButton("Accept ");                    //accept button if clicked return nothing happen 
    AcceptButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    AcceptButton.setEnabled(false);     
    AcceptButton.setBounds(556, 471, 89, 23);
    panel.add(AcceptButton);

    final JButton DenyButton = new JButton("Deny");                 // deny button if clicked return new InfoViewModel without the selected
    DenyButton.setEnabled(false);

    DenyButton.setBounds(682, 471, 89, 23);
    panel.add(DenyButton);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();   // infoview 
    scrollPane.setBounds(274, 36, 497, 435);
    panel.add(scrollPane);      
    Infotable = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(Infotable);

    addtomodel(clientees);                               //test case
    final JList<String> ClientRequestList = new JList<String>(Lmodel);
    ClientRequestList.setBounds(20, 36, 209, 578);
    panel.add(ClientRequestList);
    ClientRequestList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
            if (ClientRequestList.getSelectedValue() != null)
            {



            if (!arg0.getValueIsAdjusting()) 
            {
                final DefaultTableModel EmptyTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(); //  to clear inforview table everytime a different item is selected
                InfoViewModel=                  EmptyTableModel;
                Infotable.setModel(InfoViewModel);//    

                int index=0;



                for(int i =0; i <clientees.size(); i++ ){
                    if(clientees.get(i).getName()== ClientRequestList.getSelectedValue())
                    {
                        index=i;
                        break;
                    }}
                final int index2=index;                 
              if(ClientRequestList.getSelectedValue()==clientees.get(index2).getName())
              {

                InfoViewModel.addColumn("Client's Attribute");
                InfoViewModel.addColumn("Client's Attribute Value");        
                InfoViewModel.addRow(new Object[]{"Name", clientees.get(index2).getName()});
                InfoViewModel.addRow(new Object[]{"Phone Number", clientees.get(index2).getPhone()});
                InfoViewModel.addRow(new Object[]{"A/D",clientees.get(index2).GetADflag() });   
                Infotable.setModel(InfoViewModel);
                if(clientees.get(index2).GetADflag()=="Not Set")
                {
                    DenyButton.setEnabled(true);      
                    DenyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            clientees.get(index2).SetADflag("false");
                             if(ClientRequestList.getSelectedIndex()>=0)
                                Lmodel.remove(ClientRequestList.getSelectedIndex());                                                                  
                            ClientRequestList.setModel(Lmodel);

                        }
                    });
                    AcceptButton.setEnabled(true);
                    AcceptButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                             System.out.println("Current selection: " +     clientees.get(index2));
                            clientees.get(index2).SetADflag("true");
                            AcceptButton.setEnabled(false);
                            DenyButton.setEnabled(false);


                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    AcceptButton.setEnabled(false);
                    DenyButton.setEnabled(false);

                }
              }
            }
        }}
    });

    AcceptButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
    });

    JLabel lblDriver = new JLabel("Available Driver");
    lblDriver.setBounds(781, 24, 247, 14);
    panel.add(lblDriver);

    JLabel lblClientsInfo = new JLabel("Client's Info");
    lblClientsInfo.setBounds(274, 24, 497, 14);
    panel.add(lblClientsInfo);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
        },
        new String[] {
        }
    ));
    table.setBounds(781, 37, 395, 578);
    panel.add(table);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Driver", null, panel_1, null);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnUpdateDriverList = new JButton("Add Driver");
    btnUpdateDriverList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    btnUpdateDriverList.setBounds(712, 540, 194, 48);
    panel_1.add(btnUpdateDriverList);

    JButton btnRemoveDriver = new JButton("Remove Driver ");
    btnRemoveDriver.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    btnRemoveDriver.setBounds(10, 602, 194, 48);
    panel_1.add(btnRemoveDriver);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Driver List");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 238, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel);

    JList list = new JList();
    list.setBounds(10, 53, 238, 535);
    panel_1.add(list);

    table_1 = new JTable();
    table_1.setBounds(275, 54, 427, 535);
    panel_1.add(table_1);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Driver Info");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(275, 40, 427, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Name");
    lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(712, 480, 104, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_2);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(837, 477, 86, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblCarLicense = new JLabel("Car license");
    lblCarLicense.setBounds(712, 505, 104, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblCarLicense);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(837, 502, 86, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField_1);

    JLabel lblStudentId = new JLabel("Student ID");
    lblStudentId.setBounds(712, 455, 104, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblStudentId);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setColumns(10);
    textField_2.setBounds(837, 452, 86, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField_2);

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Statistic ", null, panel_2, null);

    JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Switch On/Off", null, panel_3, null);
    panel_3.setLayout(null);


    JButton btnTurnOn = new JButton("Turn On");
    btnTurnOn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    btnTurnOn.setBounds(79, 137, 782, 318);
    panel_3.add(btnTurnOn);




}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public DefaultListModel addtomodel(ArrayList<Client> test)
{
    for(int i =0; i <test.size(); i++ )
    Lmodel.addElement(test.get(i).getName());
    return Lmodel;
  }
}
```

////New class starting here///

```
public class Client {
private  String Name; 
private String Phone; 
private String ADflag; // using it to test the button to press once 

public  String getName()
{
    return Name;
}
public String getPhone()
{
    return Phone;
}
Client ()
{
    setName("Tony Candy");
    Phone = "911";
    ADflag = "Not Set";
}
public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}
public void SetADflag(String state)
{
    ADflag= state;  
}
public String GetADflag()
{
    return ADflag;

}
}
```

for some Reason the Jlist saved my selection and eveytime i change my selection it was also saved a long with it so when i press accept therefore setting the set.adflag[true] to all of values that was saved during the selecting process

Comment: Put your "data" in the `JList` and stop using a separate `clientees`.  When you get the `selecetdValue` from the `JList` it will be whatever object is in currently in your `clientees` `List`, thus saving you a serious amount of work

Comment: is that the reason why every time i change my selection and the accept button change both of them ?

Comment: I have no idea, I can't debug your code, BUT, it would eliminate the guess work

Comment: give me a sec let me edit the code

Comment: done now i think the code is run-able

Comment: `if (clientees.get(i).getName() == ClientRequestList.getSelectedValue())`? You shouldn't compare `String`'s in this manner, now, go back to my first comment

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Thank you kind sir i found out the problem ya ur right... it is the == that jack me up